# Как реализовать магазин в игре

Tags: php

Добрый день, столкнулся со сложностями реализации магазина в игре на php. Этот кусок кода отвечает за вывод вещей из БД.

```
        $query = ("SELECT * FROM `shop`");
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        while ($show = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
         echo $show["description"]."<br>"."Характеристики:<br> Скорость ".$show["speed"]."<br>"."Скилл ".$show["scill"]."<br>"."Стоимость ".$money = $show["money"]."<br>";
         echo "
            <form method=\"get\">
                <button name=\"<php $money; ?>\">Купить</button>    
            </form>";

         }
}
```

К ней я прикрутил форму, которую поместил в цикл. Всё работает, каждая кнопка отвечает за свою стоимость, но как теперь мне её купить? Я пробовал методом `if(isset$_GET[$mon]){//выполняй этот код}`Но скорее всего перемеренная `$money` не работает в $_GET. В GET я вставлял переменную которую прогнал через фильтр 
`$exp = explode("%",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$two = explode("+",$exp[1]);
$mon = $two[1];` и получил на выходе стоимость вещи, которая была указана в адресной строке браузера.

Перед покупкой я хочу сделать условие, если у персонажа достаточно денег, продай, после запиши id вещи в ячейку БД. Повторюсь, для этого мне нужен метод GET, если была нажата кнопка, выполняй выше указанное условие if. Если я не правильно мыслю, поправьте.

Comment: почитайте о том, как должен выглядеть html-код формы, какие запросы get\post и для чего использовать и как осуществляется передача параметров формы в `$_POST`/`$_GET` массивы. А затем сравнить с тем, что у вас сейчас получается в html-коде.

Comment: У меня это условие не работает `f(isset($_GET['$mon'])){
     if($mon = $money_user["money"]){echo "Вы приобрели товар";}else{echo "У вас недостаточно денег";}
    }` или я не туга клоню?

Comment: HTTP метод GET должен быть идемпотентным. Браузер имеет право вызывать его несколько раз.

Comment: var_dump $_GET['что-нужно-получить'] открывает порой удивительные вещи. Порой оказывается, что выдается или NULL, или вообще неожиданные штуки :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo "
        <form method=\"get\">
            <button name=\"<php $money; ?>\">Купить</button>    
        </form>";
```

Из данного куска кода стоит предположить что в name пойдет значение типа `<php 123p; ?>`. Соответственно значение хранится в $_GET["< php 123p; ? >"], где 123р это Ваша переменная $money. Чтобы все заработало, поправте этот кусок так:

```
echo "
        <form method=\"get\">
            <button name=\"$money\">Купить</button>    
        </form>";
```

Comment: Ваш код работает лучше моего, спасибо. Но у меня по прежнему не получается связать метод GET с name $money.

Comment: Объясню, у меня на каждую кнопку весит своя цена, к примеру первая кнопка имеет цену 200 монет, вторая 100. Я её занес в ` <button name=\"$money\">Купить</button> ` //Где $money это стоимость вещи. Теперь методом `if(isset($_GET["<php $money; ?>"])){` которая тоже находиться в цикле, я хочу чтобы переменная $money имела тоже стоимость кнопки, чтобы связать  ` <button name=\"$money\">Купить</button> ` а не прописывать вручную if(isset($_GET["<php //Сюда стоимость; ?>"])). Но я даже не знаю что в $_GET["<php $money; ?>"]) программа подставляет, через print_r выводил, нечего не выводит.

Comment: `var_dump($_GET["<?php $money; ?>"]);` выводит на экран NULL

Comment: Всё заработало. `f(isset($_GET["$money"])){` и собственно ваш код.

Comment: Собственно в `if(isset($_GET["$money"])){..` внутри ГЕТ параметра, в Вашем случае, переменную лучше писать без ковычек, т.к. можно случайно пропустить там пробел или другой символ, что приведет к тому что будет происходить обращение к несуществующему элементу. Т.е. `if(isset($_GET[$money])){..`